# How can Hibernate 5 be configured to save java.util.Calendar the same as Hibernate 4?

Tags: hibernate

When upgrading from Hibernate 4 to 5, Calendar objects from a other timezones are saved differently. Can Hibernate 5 be configured to behave the same way Hibernate 4 did?

ex.

- MySQL column datatype: datetime
- Computer Timezone: US/Eastern
- Computer Time: 2021-04-28 22:17:51
- Calendar object Timezone: Canada/Pacific
- Using Hibernate 4, this saves in a MySQL database as: 2021-04-28 22:17:51
- Using Hibernate 5, this saves in a MySQL database as: 2021-04-28 19:17:51 (Note that it saved the timezone's time)

There is a Hibernate task that may explain this: [HHH-7375](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-7375) and [commit](https://github.com/tomcat8088/hibernate/commit/3e73948dae900e6d63030e1bc1bf5ac40e88e361)

In Hibernate 5, this happens whether or not the object is annotated with @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)

Object class

```
@Entity
public class TimeTestObj {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    Integer id;
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP) // Happens whether or not this is set
    Calendar calendar;

    public TimeTestObj(Calendar calendar) {
        this.calendar = calendar;
    }

}
```

Sample Scenario

```
public class TimeTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SessionFactory sessionFactory = buildSessionFactory();
        
        // NOTE that the computer is in US/Eastern timezone
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Canada/Pacific"));
            
        TimeTestObj timeTestObject = new TimeTestObj(calendar);
        
        Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        Transaction trans = session.beginTransaction();

        session.saveOrUpdate(timeTestObject);
        trans.commit();
        
        sessionFactory.close();
    }
    
    private static SessionFactory buildSessionFactory() {
        Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
        configuration.addAnnotatedClass(TimeTestObj.class);
        configuration.configure();
            
        //For hibernate 4.0+
        //ServiceRegistryBuilder srb = new ServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(configuration.getProperties());
        //ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry = srb.buildServiceRegistry();
            
        //For hibernate 5
        ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(configuration.getProperties()).build();

        return configuration.buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry);
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you please clarify a bit what is the difference. What timezone was used in Hibernate 4, and what is used by  Hibernate 5?

Comment: The difference (and the whole issue) is that a different value is saved in the database (offset by timezone).
Both Hibernate 4 and 5 are using the same code and timezone (Canada/Pacific) as listed in the example.

Comment: Do you use `java -Duser.timezone` option? Do you use `hibernate.jdbc.time_zone` ? Maybe [this part](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#basic-datetime-time-zone) of the documentation will be helpful.

Comment: We have tried using hibernate.jdbc.time_zone = "UTC" but the behaviour is the same. (Thanks for the suggestions!)

Comment: Could you please clarify what exactly hibernate 4... and hibernate 5... versions do you use?

Comment: Tested with Hibernate 4.2.1, 4.3.11, 5.0.0 and 5.4.0

Comment: @HeavyE I don't suppose you ever solved this satisfactorily? I think I'm running into a similar issue currently.

Comment: @quantumferret I believe the solution we used was to correct the timezone in the Calendar after loading (for every Calendar, for every object DAO). If you can, try using ZonedDateTime to see if that has the issue resolved.

Comment: @HeavyE yeah, the problematic code was big mix of jodatime, util.Date and util.Calendar, and a bit of the java.time classes here and there. What ended up working for me was completely replacing all of the util usages with OffsetDateTime, replacing as much of the jodatime usages with java.time as possible without changing the API, and then not adjusting OffsetDateTime objects to UTC when inserting or getting records from the database, but handling that as needed elsewhere in the code.

That I wasn't able to completely replace Jodatime still irks me, but that's a task for another day...